# Aggregate ID-property-value records in Hive

Tags: sql, hive, group-by

I have a table  in the following format

```
ID  Property  Value

1    name      Tim

1    location  USA

1    age       30

2    name      Jack

2    location  UK

2    age       27
```

And I would like an output in the following format

```
ID  name  location age

1   Tim    USA     30

2   Jack   UK      27
```

In python I can do

```
table_agg = table.groupby('ID')[['Property','Value']].apply(lambda x: dict(x.values))

p = pd.DataFrame(list(table_agg))
```

How to write the query in Hive?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [collect_list,map](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF) functions to group the data then access the **`array`** based on key.

***Example:***

```
hive> create table t1(id int,property string,valu string) stored as orc;
hive> insert into t1 values(1,"name","Tim"),(1,"location","USA"),(1,"age","30"),(2,"name","Jack"),(2,"location","UK"),(2,"age","27");

hive> select id,
       va[0]["name"]name,
       va[1]["location"]location,
       va[2]["age"]age 
      from (
           select id,collect_list(map(property,value))va 
               from <table_name> group by id
          )t;
```

***Result:***

```
id      name    location        age
1       Tim     USA             30
2       Jack    UK              27
```

Comment: Thanks @Shu! I had an error trying this though. The error message is: 'UDFArgumentTypeException Only primitive type arguments are accepted but map<string,string> was passed as parameter 1. I guess that is because map is not considered as primitive type in Hive? Any thoughts how to get around this?

Comment: @lgao weird!, I added `my create table statements` and able to run the query without any issues in **Hive 1.1 and 2.1**. if you are having `different datatypes` then add your hive create table statement to the question and error that you are getting!

Comment: I am also facing same issue FAILED: UDFArgumentTypeException Only primitive type arguments are accepted but map<string,int> was passed as parameter 1

Comment: @dhnsh. I was looking at below problem to solve it in hive but facing an issue while collecting map values like you did. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57541507/effective-way-to-groupby-without-using-pivot-in-pyspark?noredirect=1#comment101547274_57541507