# effective way to groupby without using pivot in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a query where I need to calculate memory utilization using pyspark. I had achieved this with python pandas using pivot but now I need to do it in pyspark and pivoting would be an expensive function so I would like to know if there is any alternative in pyspark for this solution

```
time_stamp          Hostname    kpi kpi_subtype value_current
2019/08/17 10:01:05 Server1     memory  Total       100
2019/08/17 10:01:06 Server1     memory  used        35
2019/08/17 10:01:09 Server1     memory  buffer      8
2019/08/17 10:02:04 Server1     memory  cached      10
2019/08/17 10:01:05 Server2     memory  Total       100
2019/08/17 10:01:06 Server2     memory  used        42
2019/08/17 10:01:09 Server2     memory  buffer      7
2019/08/17 10:02:04 Server2     memory  cached      9
2019/08/17 10:07:05 Server1     memory  Total       100
2019/08/17 10:07:06 Server1     memory  used        35
2019/08/17 10:07:09 Server1     memory  buffer      8
2019/08/17 10:07:04 Server1     memory  cached      10
2019/08/17 10:08:05 Server2     memory  Total       100
2019/08/17 10:08:06 Server2     memory  used        35
2019/08/17 10:08:09 Server2     memory  buffer      8
2019/08/17 10:08:04 Server2     memory  cached      10
```

Which need to be transformed to

```
time_stamp      Hostname    kpi Percentage
2019-08-17 10:05:00 Server1     memory  17
2019-08-17 10:05:00 Server2     memory  26
2019-08-17 10:10:00 Server1     memory  17
2019-08-17 10:10:00 Server2     memory  17
```

Python code i used

```
df3 = pd.read_csv('/home/yasin/Documents/IMI/Data/memorry sample.csv')
df3['time_stamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df3['time_stamp'])
ns5min=5*60*1000000000 
df3['time_stamp'] = pd.to_datetime(((df3['time_stamp'].astype(np.int64) // ns5min + 1 ) * ns5min))
df4 = df3.pivot_table('value_current' , ['time_stamp' , 'Hostname ' , 'kpi' ], 'kpi_subtype')
df4 = df4.reset_index()
df4['Percentage'] = ((df4['Total'] - (df4['Total'] - df4['used'] + df4['buffer'] + df4['cached'])) / df4['Total']) * 100
```

Looking for a to replicate this in pyspark and a more efficient way in python as pivot is an expensive operation and I need to perform this every 5 mins on a really large dataset

Comment: each time you will be having multiple record sets for server 1 & 2 ?

Comment: yes every 5 mins we will be getting the same set of data

Comment: What is the timeframe in which first set of server1&server2 lies? Is it 5 mins? will it extend beyond 5 mins or it will remain in that timeframe

Comment: It will be the same set of servers every 5 mins. in real there will be about 20000 servers

Answer (score 3):

Pivoting is expensive when the list of values that are translated to columns is unknown. Spark has an overloaded `pivot` method that takes them as an argument.

```
def pivot(pivotColumn: String, values: Seq[Any])
```

In case they aren't known Spark must sort and collect the distinct values from your dataset. Otherwise, the logic is pretty straightforward and described [here](https://databricks.com/blog/2016/02/09/reshaping-data-with-pivot-in-apache-spark.html).

> The implementation adds a new logical operator (o.a.s.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.Pivot). That logical operator is translated by a new analyzer rule (o.a.s.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.ResolvePivot) that currently translates it into an aggregation with lots of if statements, one expression per pivot value.
>
> For example, df.groupBy("A", "B").pivot("C", Seq("small", "large")).sum("D") would be translated into the equivalent of df.groupBy("A", "B").agg(expr(“sum(if(C = ‘small’, D, null))”), expr(“sum(if(C = ‘large’, D, null))”)). You could have done this yourself but it would get long and possibly error prone quickly.

Without pivoting I would do something like that:

```
val in = spark.read.csv("input.csv")
      //cast to the unix timestamp
      .withColumn("timestamp", unix_timestamp($"time_stamp", "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss").cast(TimestampType))
      .drop($"time_stamp")
```

Now we can group our dataset by the time window with hostname and collect KPI metrics into a map.
There is an excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41819275/how-to-use-groupby-to-collect-rows-into-a-map) describing just that.

```
val joinMap = udf { values: Seq[Map[String, Double]] => values.flatten.toMap }

val grouped = in.groupBy(window($"timestamp", "5 minutes"), $"Hostname")
  .agg(joinMap(collect_list(map($"kpi_subtype", $"value_current".cast(DoubleType)))).as("metrics"))
```

Output

```
+------------------------------------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
|window                                    |Hostname|metrics                                                      |
+------------------------------------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
|[2019-08-17 10:00:00, 2019-08-17 10:05:00]|Server1 |[Total -> 100.0, used -> 35.0, buffer -> 8.0, cached -> 10.0]|
|[2019-08-17 10:00:00, 2019-08-17 10:05:00]|Server2 |[Total -> 100.0, used -> 42.0, buffer -> 7.0, cached -> 9.0] |
|[2019-08-17 10:05:00, 2019-08-17 10:10:00]|Server1 |[Total -> 100.0, used -> 35.0, buffer -> 8.0, cached -> 10.0]|
|[2019-08-17 10:05:00, 2019-08-17 10:10:00]|Server2 |[Total -> 100.0, used -> 35.0, buffer -> 8.0, cached -> 10.0]|
+------------------------------------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Now we define some aliases   and a simple select statement:

```
val total = col("metrics")("Total")
val used = col("metrics")("used")
val buffer = col("metrics")("buffer")
val cached = col("metrics")("cached")

val result = grouped.select($"window", $"Hostname",
          (total - ((total - used + buffer + cached) / total) * 100).as("percentage"))
```

And here we go:

```
+------------------------------------------+--------+----------+
|window                                    |Hostname|percentage|
+------------------------------------------+--------+----------+
|[2019-08-17 10:00:00, 2019-08-17 10:05:00]|Server1 |17.0      |
|[2019-08-17 10:00:00, 2019-08-17 10:05:00]|Server2 |26.0      |
|[2019-08-17 10:05:00, 2019-08-17 10:10:00]|Server1 |17.0      |
|[2019-08-17 10:05:00, 2019-08-17 10:10:00]|Server2 |17.0      |
+------------------------------------------+--------+----------+
```

Comment: Hi... I believe this code is in scala. Since the rest of my code is in pyspark need to integrate this with my existing code.

Comment: All of the used functions are Spark ones, don't you have them in python?

Comment: joinMap = udf ({ values: Seq[Map[String, Double]] => values.flatten.toMap} ). I modified this to python but I am getting a sytax error for the symbol '=>'

Comment: Use `Python` UDF syntax instead: https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/udf-python.html.
Also, your types are different, here you have an example for python. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41288622/pyspark-create-maptype-column-from-existing-columns

Comment: Thanks. I have come up with the alternative pyspark code

Answer (score 1):

1st is using pivot in spark and the 2nd is using map.

> 1st Solution

```
df = sql.read.csv("/home/yasin/Documents/IMI/Data/memorry sample.csv", header = "True").withColumn("timestamp", unix_timestamp("time_stamp", "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss").cast(TimestampType())).drop("time_stamp")
df = df.withColumn("unixtime",unix_timestamp(df["timestamp"],"yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"))
df = df.withColumn("unixtime2",(round(df["unixtime"]/300)*300).cast("timestamp"))
df = df.groupBy("unixtime2" , "Hostname" , "kpi").pivot("kpi_subtype").agg(mean(df["value_current"]))
df = df.withColumn("Percentage", (df["Total"] - (df["Total"] - df["Used"] + df["buffer"] + df["cached"])) /df["Total"] * 100)
```

> 2nd Solution

```
df = sql.read.csv("/home/yasin/Documents/IMI/Data/memorry sample.csv", header = "True").withColumn("timestamp", unix_timestamp("time_stamp", "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss").cast(TimestampType())).drop("time_stamp")
df = df.withColumn("unixtime",unix_timestamp(df["timestamp"],"yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"))
df = df.withColumn("unixtime2",(round(df["unixtime"]/300)*300).cast("timestamp"))
df = df.withColumn("value_current2",df["value_current"].cast("Float"))
df = df.groupBy("unixtime2" , "Hostname" , "kpi").agg(collect_list(create_map("kpi_subtype","value_current2")).alias("mapped"))
nn=df.withColumn("formula" ,  ( df["mapped"][0]["Total"].cast("Float") - (( df["mapped"][0]["Total"].cast("Float") - df["mapped"][1]["used"].cast("Float")  + df["mapped"][2]["buffer"].cast("Float") + df["mapped"][3]["cached"].cast("Float") ) / df["mapped"][0]["Total"].cast("Float") ) * 100).cast("Float"))
```

Comment: nice. looking some way to do it in Hive

Comment: I have not used hive so not aware about it.